# How to search in a array of model objects based on the value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This is an example of my model object

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init(id: Int, name: String, age: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id")
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        self.age = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
    }
}
```

I am creating some person objects and adding to an array

```
    let newPerson1 = Person(id:"101", name: "Joe1", age: 10)
    let newPerson2 = Person(id:"102", name: "Joe2", age: 11)
    var people = [Person]()
    people.append(newPerson1)
    people.append(newPerson2)

    //saving to file
    let documentsDirectory =  try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let listOfTasksURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("listOfTasks.plist")
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(people, toFile: listOfTasksURL.path)

    // retrieving from the file
    var peopleArray = [Person]()
    if let tempArr: [Person] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: listOfTasksURL.path) as? [Person] {
        peopleArray = tempArr
    }
    print(peopleArray)

    let data = peopleArray[0]
    print(data.id)
```

I am getting the values succesfully.
I want to search for the `'Person'` object with id `'101'` and delete it from the array and save the modified array back to file. 
I want to return a flag if the item is not in the list and add the item to list if its not there.
How can i accomplish this.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index(where:)` to get the index of that object and after getting index you can easily remove that object from array.

```
func deleteObject(with id: Int) -> Bool
    if let index = people.index(where: { $0.id == id }) {
        people.remove(at: index)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

//Now use this method like this
if deleteObject(with: 101)  {
    //object is successfully deleted now save data in array
    let documentsDirectory =  try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let listOfTasksURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("listOfTasks.plist")
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(people, toFile: listOfTasksURL.path)
}
else {
    //object is not present in array add new object
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is i am using the correct way to save the array to the file ?

Comment: @proCoder It looks ok, Are you facing any issue with it?

Comment: Yes its working nice , but how can i save the modified array back to file. I want to return a flag if the item is not in the list and add the item if its not there.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Thank you

Comment: @proCoder Check the edited answer :)

Comment: Thank you. How can i delete based on two values , means id and name.

Comment: @proCoder You just need to change condition like this `if let index = people.index(where: { $0.id == id && $0.name == "searchName" }) {`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if let expectedIndex = people.index(where: { $0.id == 101 }) {
    people.remove(at: expectedIndex)
}
```

**More:** [Trailing Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102)